# How can I get a select drop-down menu based in terms of the a vocabulary to display in a block or a theme?

Tags: 7, navigation

I need to get a select drop-down menu based in terms of the a vocabulary.  I need to display this select drop-down in a zone of the theme or in a block not in the edit/create forms.

I have a vocabulary named:  "myterms" and I have the following list of terms in this vocabulary:

```
term1
term2
term3
term4
```

I need a menu - select -drop-down that shows term1 and term3 to select and when I put click in the term1 or term3 go to the respective page.  In the menu select drop-down won't show all terms, I need to choose the terms.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://drupal.org/project/entityreference? works well for me. basically your turn the field of "term" into a drop-down select on Node edit forms and a link on content.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.  I'll update my post to say that I need to display this in a block or in a zone of the theme, not at moment to creat or edit contents. Thanks again.